# Web scraping with rvest - login not working - flightradar24.com

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler, rvest, webharvest

I'm trying to harvest data from www.flightradar24.com using rvest. I've got a subscription, so I want to log in and get access to more data. This is the code I'm using to log in (I'm using my email and password instead of "email" and "password"):

```
library(rvest)

url0 = "https://www.flightradar24.com/"
session = html_session(url0)
form = html_form(session)[[1]]
filled_form = set_values(form, 'email'="email", 'password'="password")
session_loggedin = submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

I get the following message:

```
Submitting with '<unnamed>'
```

I want to check whether this is actually working, so I'm trying with this:

```
jump_to(session_loggedin, "https://www.flightradar24.com/account")
```

And this is the message I get:

```
<session> https://www.flightradar24.com/premium
Status: 200
Type:   text/html; charset=utf-8
Size:   98649
```

As you can see, it's going to https://www.flightradar24.com/premium (website where you can compare the different subscriptions) instead of https://www.flightradar24.com/account (your account page once you log in).

I've tried grabbing the data from this website https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/ln-lnc using *html_table*, but it only captures the data included in the basic subscription, so that also implies that I'm not successfully logging in.

Any help would be very much appreciated.